# Cannot use converter in xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

I'm going to use converters in binding...
I tried to add converters in Application.Resources but it says that "Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built"

**App.xaml**

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:MySchool.Converters;assembly=MySchool"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="MySchool.App">
    <Application.Resources>

        <converters:SubConverter x:Key="subInverter"/>
        <converters:CompConverter x:Key="compInverter"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

**CompConverter.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MySchool.Converters
{
    public class CompConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (int)value > (int)parameter;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if ((bool)value)
                return parameter;

            //it's false, so don't bind it back
            throw new Exception("CompConverter: It's false, I won't bind back.");
        }
    }
}
```

**SubConverter.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Text;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MySchool.Converters
{
    public class SubConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (int)value - (int)parameter;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return (int)value + (int)parameter;
        }
    }
}
```

**News.xaml**

```
<Label
    Text="{Binding attachmentsCount, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource subInverter}, StringFormat='{0} Images...'}"
    IsVisible="{Binding attachmentsCount, ConverterParameter=1, Converter={StaticResource compInverter}}"
    TextColor="#c8c8c8"
    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
    VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional"
    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="1,.9,80,40"
    BackgroundColor="#7F000000"/>
```

But it says compile error in App.xaml.

> The type 'converters:CompConverter' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

How can I do this?

Comment: I use your code and it works fine on my  side. Can you try clean and rebuild your project or restart the visual studio? Did you try build the project directly(I mean ignore the error) and did it work?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @JackHua-MSFT.
I ignored error, but it shows blank space (it shows label when not use converter).

Comment: What's the value of attachmentsCount when you test? Is it larger than 1? I test again and it works.